# MTB Cassettes- are they universal to wheels

Tags: mountain-bike, cassette, replacement

Are cassettes all standard as fare as fit on the wheel?  For example, can I can swap out a new Shimano for my old SRAM without looking at specifications for fit?

Comment: More generally, no.  30 years ago or so there were mostly only 5-speed "freewheels" and it wasn't much of an issue, but simultaneously the maximum number of speeds increased (slowly) from 5 to 11 (or so I hear), with varying cog spacings (and axle lengths), and the "freewheel" became a "freehub", with several variations.  Be wary if you are attempting to interchange between generations or genres of bikes.

Comment: The poster said SRAM. SRAM didn't exist prior to 1987 so they've only been around in the cassette era. A more realistic concern is if you're running SRAM 1x in which case your cassette will have a XD driver body which is not compatible with Shimano cassettes.

Answer (score 4):

There are currently 4 MTB freehub/cassette standards for SRAM/Shimano drive trains:

- 7 speed - Shimano/SRAM - based on Shimano HG
- 8/9/10 speed - Shimano/SRAM (a 7 speed cassette with a 4.5mm spacer also fits) based on Shimano HG
- Shimano 11 speed - fits an 8/9/10 freehub (MTB only) - based on Shimano HG
- SRAM 11 speed - XD driver freehub - SRAM proprietary system

Campagnolo has two spline patterns also, 8 speed and 9/10 speed.

Unless you a running a SRAM 1x drivetrain it's generally safe to say cassettes will be compatible for the same number of gears.